# Adjective or adverb after "arranged"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> The two objects were arranged (orthogonal | orthogonally) to each other.

Does "orthogonal" relate to the verb, or to the two objects? In other words, do I need to use the adverb or the adjective?

Comment: It would take an adverb, but [flat adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb) are a thing, so "arranged orthogonal to each other" is not entirely incorrect. (Though some strict grammarians would disagree.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you restructure the sentence, you could use either form, but in its current form you should use the **adverb** because you are describing *how* the objects are arranged, not simply describing the objects themselves. "Orthogonally" answers the question, "How were the objects arranged?".

> The two objects were orthogonal to each other.
>
> The two objects were arranged orthogonally to each other.
>
> The two objects were arranged such that they were orthogonal to each other.

Comment: "to each other" is redundant here. "Orthogonality" (in the mathematical sense) is by definition a relationship between two objects. If you delete "to each other", it is obvious that "The two objects were arranged orthogonal."  is wrong (an adverb should follow the verb).

Comment: In three dimensional space, two objects can be orthogonal to a third, or just towards each other. So the "to each other" is quite an important part, because it distinguishes those cases.

Answer (score 2):

It's the adverb you need. Orthogonally. Although orthoganality implies arrangement, so you could just say the objects were orthogonal (to each other).